# content of modal bootstrap deleted after hide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, bootstrap-modal

i'm working with Mvc dot.net
I have a modal of bootstrap in which I have inserted a Kendo UI upload widget. The problem is when I open and then close modal, the modal content is deleted magically from the DOM.

The code of the modal dialog is this:

```
<div id="modalUploadAllegato" class="modal hide fade">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Carica File</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden" id="praticaAssociata" name="praticaAssociata" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="tipologia" name="tipologia" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="associa" name="associa" value="" />
    @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("files")
        .Multiple(false)
        .Async(a => a.Save("SaveAllegato", "Claim").AutoUpload(false))
        .Events(e =>
        {
            e.Success("function (e){ uploadSuccess(e.response.idAllegato, $('#praticaAssociata').val(), $('#tipologia').val(), e.response.fileName, $('#associa').val()); }");
            e.Upload("function (e){ e.data = { idPratica:$('#praticaAssociata').val(), denuncia:$('#tipologia').val(), gruppo:$('#associa').val() } }");
            e.Error("function (e){ alert('Errore nel salvataggio del file (solo pdf)'); }");
        }))

</div>
```

Anyone know how the modal-body is deleted after modal hide?

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you would need to disable the original hiding action and override the it with your own.  This is how you over-ride the default hiding action in Bootstrap:

### Bootstrap 3

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //<-disable the original closing event
    //do your own closing action here

})
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals -> Events

### Bootstrap 2.3.2

```
$('#myModal').on('hide', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //<-disable the original closing event
    //do your own closing action here
})
```

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals -> Events

Comment: sorry but doesn't work, i try this:     $('#modalUploadAllegato').on('hide', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#modalUploadAllegato').css('display','none')}); but nothing

Comment: You really need to get in to the nitty gritty of bootstrap modal html using firebug to know which elements need to be hidden, etc.  It creates html in your code and you need to handle that.

Comment: I've tried but nothing, this is a mistery, i don't understand how is possible. Every time the modal disappear the content is deleted. Only for this modal. Even if i delete the kendo helpers.

Comment: also if i create other modal in the view, when i close them the body disappear!

Comment: Why is the content being deleted?   It seems crazy I would have to preventDefault.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the root cause of this issue, but changing the place of the modal in the HTML contributed to fixing the issue.